# Multiple Filters on HTML Table

Tags: jquery, html, filter, html-table

I have a table with some data in and have added a filter for max price which works great, but I need to add a second filter that works with the first.

For example if the user selects a maximum price of £15 with a minimum of 20GB data how would I got about filtering this? I have tried to duplicate the jQuery code with different classes and ids but no luck...

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/jqWAT/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the ID, you can't use the same name or id. You should add

```
var price = $('#filter').val();
var data = $('#filter2').val();
```

and do the same function for the data filter:

```
$('tr td.data').each(function() {
     if ($(this).text().substring(0, 2) < data)
     {
          $(this).parent().hide();
     }
});
```